# I can not debug in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

On my mac machine I can not debug java code and every time I got the following error in the console

"ERROR: transport error 202: send failed: Invalid argument"

I turn off firewall , restart machine and I still getting same problem

Comment: What are you trying to debug? Does this happen for a simple "Hello World" type application? Is your debug config set up to "connect to a remote application" or just debug as "java application" ?

Comment: it is just debugging basic java code. I create Hello World example and I got same problem!

Comment: I can not. I have to use it since I'm using some modelling implementation project under eclipse.

Comment: To confirm, you're selecting "Debug as..." > "Java Application" ?

Comment: Yes, Debug as..." > "Java Application" for Hello World example

Answer (score 0):

There is a [page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug/FAQ#J9_JRE_Support) about this problem that can have many origins that are generally due to a misconfiguration. Here is its content :

1. Check your `/etc/hosts` (linux) or `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` If there is no mapping for 'localhost' than the debugger cannot resolve connecting to the local VM via TCP. Following is an example of a hosts file with a correct mapping.
2. If you edit the launching environment (via the 'Environment' tab in the launch dialog) and have selected to 'replace my environment', you must ensure that the variables you specify as replacements are sufficient for launching. More specifically, you have to include all of the environment variables that your system and Eclipse needs to launch. The safest course of action when you want select the 'replace my environment' is to add all of the variables and your own, and to only remove those which you know for a fact are not required by your system or Eclipse.
3. It could be that there is some garbage text in your environment. To find out try typing either `cmd.exe /C set` (in Windows) or `env` (in Linux or Mac).

   The output produced should look like the following, where there are variables followed by an '=', followed by the value of the variable. (Only vor version < 3.3.1)
4. if you have the JRE you wish to use for launching installed in a jdk path, the debugger will not start complaining about its inability to find system libraries. For example, lets say you have Java 6 installed in C:\java\jdk6. Now lets say that in Eclipse you have your default JRE (the one you want to use for launching) set to the installed path C:\java\jdk6. Pre-3.3.1 debugging will not work because we would scan the current directory to find the system libraries needed to debug, and find none. The problem was that we were not correctly appending paths in our debugger to find the system libraries in the JRE folder of the install location. This has been fixed in Eclipse 3.3.1.

Comment: initially the hosts file has localhost entry, but still getting same problem Moreover, i'm using latest version of eclipse.